# node_load showing incorrect data

Tags: drupal-7, hook, nodes

I am new to Drupal 7.

I am trying to load data of a particular node whose type and title is being passed as a parameter:

```
$param = array(
'type' => 'media',
'title' => 'Home Logo Bottom Image',
'status' => 1,
);

// Getting node details
$result = node_load($param);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);

stdClass Object
(
    [vid] => 1
    [uid] => 1
    [title] => Career Tip 1
    [log] => 
    [status] => 1
    [comment] => 2
    [promote] => 1
    [sticky] => 0
    [nid] => 1
    [type] => career_tips
    [language] => und
    [created] => 1377871907
    [changed] => 1377871907
    [tnid] => 0
    [translate] => 0
    [revision_timestamp] => 1377871907
    [revision_uid] => 1
    [body] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => If you meet a woman doing a STEM job that sounds even remotely interesting to you, see if you can stop by her office for an “informational interview.” At the meeting, ask her every single question you have, even if they seem obvious or silly.
                            [summary] => 
                            [format] => full_html
                            [safe_value] => 
If you meet a woman doing a STEM job that sounds even remotely interesting to you, see if you can stop by her office for an “informational interview.” At the meeting, ask her every single question you have, even if they seem obvious or silly.


                            [safe_summary] => 
                        )

                )

        )
```

The output of above code is not correct as it is showing some other title.
What i am missing here?

Also i want to fetch the custom field value of same node. so is there a single API that could return the entire data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of [node_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) function has changed in drupal 7.  The first parameter passed to node_load has to be the node id.

Use [EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.org/node/1343708) to get all the node ids matching your query and then load the node using node_load($nid);

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$title = 'Enter the title of the node you want to search for here';
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'career_tips')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->propertyCondition('title', $title);

$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $node_nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  $items = entity_load('node', $node_nids);
}

// Now $items should contain the nodes.
```

Also once you have a node object you can use [EntityMetadataWrapper](https://drupal.org/node/1021556) to extract values conviniently.

Comment: Thanks, I used     $result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')    
    ->propertyCondition('type', 'career_tips')
    ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
    ->addTag('random')
    ->range(0, 1)
    ->execute(); 
    return $result->title; but it does not return title field in the output array. In this case how would i pass the list of fields to be fetched?

Comment: EntityFieldQuery gives you ids (node ids in this case). Like i have mentioned in the answer you got to perform a node_load on the id to fetch the Node object. Once the node object is loaded use $node->title to fetch title. For more complex fields you may optionally use EntityMetadataWrapper.

Comment: This is a long process to fetch just a single record.... is not there any other api to fetch such data?

Comment: Your answer is correct but i want it to be done in a single step using any API

Answer (score 1):

You can also use node_load_multiple function, but it is deprecated. The second parameter is the conditions.

```
$node = current(node_load_multiple(array(), array(
    'title' => 'Home Logo Bottom Image',
)));
```

Comment: can i pass condition like order by rand() with limit 0,1 in this api?

Comment: the conditions accepted by node_load_multiple is against the fields in {node} table, so no its not possible to use rand() or limits.